# Passing data to the parent activity using onActivityResult

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I have 3 activities named Activity A,B and C. I want to send some data from Activity C to Activity A using the setresult() in Activity C. is it possible to achieve? 
Note: I don't want to recreate the Activity A.

Comment: Pass it to Activity B and then pass it to Activity A

Comment: You can setResult to Activity B and from there to Activity A, or define a variable in ApplicationClass and onResume of ActivityA you can use it.

Comment: Do you want to send some values of String?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution avoiding to pass data from C to A going through B is using the Observer Pattern. In this way A gets notified when result of C is available.

Some more information here:

- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-design-patterns-the-observer-pattern--cms-28963
- https://andhradroid.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/object-observer-pattern-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Try [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library, **easy to use** and **fast** communication between Activities, Fragments, Threads, Services, etc